Why can we assume that the kernel does not split the domain in the surjective implicit function theorem by Edgar Zeidler?
I am currently working through the Surjective Implicit Function Theorem (4.H) by Edgar Zeidler from "Applied Functional Analysis: Main Principles and Their Applications". Let $X,Y,Z$ be Banach Spaces. The theorem should allow to generate additional solutions to $F(u,v) = 0$ in a neighbourhood of $(u_0,v_0)\in X\times Y$ for a continuously Fréchet differentiable function $F\colon X\times Y\to Z$. He assumes wlog $(u_0,v_0) = (0,0)$ and instead of having a bijective partial derivative $F_v(0,0)\colon Y\to Z$ he assumes a surjective one. It is specifically stressed that the null-space of $F_v(0,0)$ does not need to split Y.
To construct a recursion sequence he assumes that for the surjective linear operator $F_v(u,v)$ and every $z\in Z$ one can find a $w(z)$ such that $F_v(u,v)w(z) = z$ and there is some $d>0$ such that $d||z||\ge||w(z)||$. I have been able to show that there is indeed such a function $w$, which has these features.
In the end he constructs a sequence with the auxilliary function $f(u,v) = F_v(u,v)v-F(u,v)$ such that $v_{m+1}=w(f(u,v_m))$ and $v_0=0$. Now as I understand, we have the elementwise inequality \begin{equation}||v_{m+1}||=||w(f(u,v_m)|| \le d||f(u,v_m)||,\end{equation} but $w(z)$ is not necessarily linear, and still he assumes that in the end from this inequality you can deduce that $||v_{m+1}-v_{m}||\le d||f(u,v_m)-f(u,v_{m-1})||$. Why does this inequality follow? In my view it is only known pointwise and not for differences of points.
This sequence is then supposed to converge to a $v$ such that $F(u,v) = 0$
Thank you very much in advance.
